# Why do I not see Wikipedia references some text while analyzing using NLP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-nl

Why do I not see Wikipedia references to **Samuel**, even though it is available while analyzing using NLP. But some entities have reference in the **Entity extraction** during google natural language-demo.

Kindly refer the below screenshot,
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the numbers below the words: `Samuel`, `colleague` and `Gnanavel`.

The Wikipedia article is related to the Entity #2 which is `Gnanavel`, not to `Samuel` which is the Entity #1.

If you click on that link it will take you to the article of [K. E. Gnanavel Raja](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K._E._Gnanavel_Raja)

Also, as per the [Entities analysis documentation](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/analyzing-entities#language-entities-string-python) you will find that, sometimes, the metadata associated to an entity includes Wikipedia URLs. This is why you might see these kind of articles for certain entities.